# How to customise my URL which is having IP Address

Tags: apache, url, ip-address, httpd.conf

Is it possible to configure my URL which has my IP address on it- like: "http://192.168.xx.yy/index.php". The situation is when I run Apache server in my PC, and load localhost in it. I know it is possible after hosting with external server, but is there any way we can configure within our localhost?

How to configure the Apache files to make this happen? I tried in my localhost, editing the "httpd.conf" by adding this inside like this - please tell me where I am getting the issue!

```
ServerName localhost:80  
HostnameLookups Off  
<VirtualHost *:80>
   # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80  
ServerName www.example.com  
ServerAlias example.com  
DocumentRoot /www/domain  
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:80>  
ServerName other.example.com  
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain  
</VirtualHost>  
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
```

Comment: You have a private IP which is not visible from Intenet. In order to access your local server from outside of your local network the router should forward requests to its external interface on port 80 to your local IP with server on it. Use http://portforward.com/ (step 2 or 3 is just ads, look carefully for continue link). And FYI - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network  If you are asking about domain name - only DNS server within the local network, or normal domain and port forwarding, or manual modification of `hosts` file on every computer from which you want to access the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play with multiple IP addresses on your machine. Configuration depends on your OS. Article [Create Multiple IP Addresses to One Single Network Interface](http://www.tecmint.com/create-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-single-network-interface/) is for linux.

But, better way is to use VirtualHosts based on host names or (simplest) on ports. So you can get http://siteA.mycoputer.localhost, http://siteB.mycomputer.localhost in the first case and http://192.168.x.y:8000, http://192.168.x.y:9000 in the second case

Here is Apache Server config example from [Apache Server 2.2 documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#purename)

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/example1
    ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/example2
    ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Dvoretsky-  Now, its interesting... Please help me how to use VirtualHosts. Iam using Windows PC.

Comment: It's simple with Apache Web Server for example. I've added example to my answer

Comment: Ok. But iam not sure of which file to edit, is it "httpd.conf"

Comment: Yes, it's `httpd.conf`

Comment: One more problem: In my WAMP Folder, i could find that there is a file named " httpd-vhosts.conf " & i could see the above contents, there. Is that the file to be modified!!